# Stop editing in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, editing, qgis-2.18

I want to create a button in a toolbar in PyQGIS/QGIS 2.18  which allows to start or stop the editing mode and the identifying mode at the same time. I can't figure out how to stop the editing mode. I tried to use stopEditing(), to no avail. Here's my code :

```
def run(self):
    if not self.iface.activeLayer():
        self.iface.messageBar().pushCritical(u'Whoops', u'Please select a layer')
    else:
        if not self.iface.activeLayer().isEditable():
            self.iface.actionPan().trigger()
            self.iface.activeLayer().startEditing()
        else:
            self.iface.actionIdentify().trigger()
            self.iface.activeLayer().stopEditing()
```

Besides `stopEditing()`, everything works as it's supposed to.

Comment: When you want to stop editing, are you wanting to commit any changes made? In which case, you could use `self.iface.activeLayer().commitChanges()`

Comment: I would like to be able to ask the user whether or not (s)he wants to commit changes.

Comment: It works, thanks! Post your comment as an answer if you want me to upvote you.

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped! Thanks, don't care about upvotes but will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is to trigger the *Toggle Editing* icon from the main window which already includes a dialog box prompting the user to confirm any changes:

```
 from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction
 iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionToggleEditing').trigger()
```